# nodejs, passportjs and sequelize with passport-local

Tags: javascript, node.js, passport.js, sequelize.js, passport-local

I need some help with a problem that I do not understand.

First of all, this is the error I got:

```
Error: Route.post() requires callback functions but got a [object Undefined]
```

I tried to use passport-local to protect my API.

I call the API like this:

```
router.route("/login")
.post(passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}) ,login.get);
```

The getToken Function looks like:

```
function get(req, res) {
res.send([{"stack": "overflow"}]);
```

}

And this is my strategy:

```
var local = new LocalStrategy(options,
function(username, password, done) {
    models.user.findOne({where:{ username: username}}).then(function(err, user) {
        if (err) { return done(err); }
        if (!user) {
            return done(null, false);
        }
        return done(null, user);
    });
});
```

What is wrong in my setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe because login.get is actually undefined. 
try something like this:

```
router.route('/login')  
 .post(passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}), 
       function (req, res, next) { 
          // callback here
       });
```

or another way could be:

```
router.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {session: false}), function (req, res) { ... });
```

Comment: login.get is defined trough: module.exports = { get }; in the login controller

Comment: so you are saying that it's defined? have you tried logging it? provide some more code if you can.

Comment: You were right, my function had the next missing in the callback. Thank you!